# Qual a forma recomendada de se indicar as melhores ações a um novo usuário?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Observando vários novos usuários no SOPT percebi que muitos deles ainda não estão habituados com as **boas práticas** da comunidade, em alguns casos eu procuro comentar nas perguntas, nas respostas e nos comentários destes usuários para indicar algumas coisas que eu sei que são de fato **boas práticas**.

Essa é a forma correta de se agir?

Existe alguma outra forma de se obter êxito ao indicar o "caminho das pedras" à quem precise?

Comment: Certamente não há nada de mal em usar comentários como forma de instruir alguém, desde que com o tom e conteúdo adequados. Talvez haja mais que possa ser feito... Vou pensar mais.

Comment: O tom é algo a ser pensando e trabalhado. Uma pequena escorregada e um usuário simplesmente fecha a conta no SOPT e desiste (fazendo o mea culpa com [um exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11788/exportar-projeto-dreamweaver-para-o-eclipse?noredirect=1#comment21087_11788)), ofender um novo usuário na tentativa de instruí-lo é extremamente frustrante para ambas as partes. Eu aprendi que um "Bem vindo ao stack overflow" ameniza um pouco o tom de crítica e surte bons efeitos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu faço assim: vou no help do site, localizo o trecho de orientação pertinente, copio e colo num comentário, seguido do link para a fonte.

Exemplo de comentário (pertinente à pergunta):

> "Verifique se a sua pergunta é contextualizada para este site. Você
>   deve fazer apenas perguntas práticas, que admitam respostas com base
>   em problemas reais que tiver. Perguntas extensas e abertas diminuem a
>   utilidade de nosso site (...) Suas perguntas devem ter um escopo
>   razoável. Se você pode imaginar um livro inteiro que responda à sua
>   pergunta, está perguntando demais." - Fonte:
>   [pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6626/site-em-uma-unica-pagina)

Quanto mais links e referências para as páginas de ajuda, melhor. Penso que estimular a leitura de todo o material de ajuda que já existe é uma boa ideia.